# MS Access Change Tables under Bound Controls

Tags: database, forms

I'm in the process of 'rationalizing' a problem where the user is required to open and work in 11 distinct databases. Everything is the same in all 11 databases - the original idea was to keep the data separate. Now, the company has done a turn.

1. There are two forms in the app - the first form collects some basic data then, on a user 'click', opens a second form where the actual work is done. A query + where clause is the record source for the 'Main Form'.
2. In each database there are several tables, most of them look-up tables. The key data table in eacgh db is called "Main Table".
3. There is no BE/FE design.

What I would like to do is create a single back end comprised of the look-up tables and the 11 'Main Tables', renaming each table with a Table Number + Main (as in "01MAIN", "02MAIN", etc.) In the first form, the user would select the target table and the main form would be .loaded with the salient info.

I was thinking that when the user determines the table they want to work with, I could somehow use table aliases in the query so that there would be no interruption with the numerous bound text boxes and check boxes on the main form.  In other words, I want the bound controls to 'see' "MAIN TABLE" even though the 'real' table would be "01MAIN", or "02MAIN", etc.

Is this doable? If so, how would the query + filter in the Open Form macro which drives the Main Form be updated to reflect the table selection.... or maybe this just won't work.

Ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by swapping out the RecordSource property instead of playing with the query SQL.  You could have a combobox on the main form which has all the relevant table names.  The main form could have a default RecordSource of the first table (01MAIN) so you don't have broken bound fields, and then when the combobox is updated, the RecordSource of the form updates to the table in question.

So for example, assuming the name of the combobox that has the table names is called cmbTables, attach this code to your main form (there's no error handling - just a quick demonstration):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strTableNames As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If tbl.Name Like "??MAIN" Then
            strTableNames = strTableNames & tbl.Name & ";"
        End If
    Next

    Me.cmbTables.RowSource = strTableNames

    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

This will populate cmbTables with the names of all tables in your database that look like xxMAIN.  Then attach this to cmbTables AfterUpdate event:

```
Private Sub cmbTables_AfterUpdate()
    Me.RecordSource = cmbTables.Value
End Sub
```

This changes the RecordSource of the form to the table selected in the combobox when a new value is selected.  Now, if all the bound field names are the same, you should be able to do this transparently and your form should update to reflect the new table data.  You can figure out how to do this with QueryDef names instead of table names if need be.  Worked for me in a quick test.